# Animate a mesh using bones rotations instead of shape keys

Tags: rendering, animation, armature, bones, shape-keys

I'm using the mesh found in this [link](http://cdn.tutsplus.com/cg/uploads/2014/02/Blender-Facial-Animation-PT1-Project_Files.rar)
which is animated using shape keys. I'm wondering how I can do the same animation but using bones (armature) instead? So if anyone could please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can drive those shapekeys with bones, this is actually the preferred way of doing facial animations. [This video](http://vimeo.com/21357304) explains in a detail how to setup the drivers and hook the bones to the shapekeys. In the first part he creates all the face-expression shapekeys and in this second one he drives them with bones.

Answer (score 0):

I've been experimenting with facial armatures!
I use envelope weights, weight paint, and bone constraints to mirror sides of the face, and I was trying to make a weird sort of pentagraph-like thing for shaping the outer mouth and cheeks

[ http://ball2000.net/blender/shapebones/ ]

Comment: I know weight painting, this is not related to my problem. My problem is that I already have an animation done using shape keys but I want to use bone and weight painting instead, but to do the same animation made by the shape keys

Comment: So you have shape key animation all done; and you want to somehow transmogrify it into armature animation? huh...  A brute-force approach would be to write a script that creates an armature with a little bone for each and every vertex; creates a pose library by applying all the transformations of each vertex to each and every bone; something like that?

Comment: I don't want to have a 4000 bone in case my mesh is 4000 vertex :) . What I'm thinking of is a bone for every shape key. What do you think?

Comment: That whole concept blows my mind.  I don't understand

Comment: This was on the related things over there-->, since I don't understand I'm not sure it helps... 

[ http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12146/most-simple-way-to-drive-shape-keys-in-python-via-armature-object?rq=1 ]

Comment: can we chat to explain what I want? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18571/discussion-between-ball2000-and-shepherd).

Comment: ehy man. Did you find a solution ? I have the same situation of you. I'm following a tutorial where it has been used the shape keys,but I don't like them because I can't modify the vertex the of character after having placed them. So,I want to find another more flexible solution,maybe like the bone constraints.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the shape driver constraint add-on to control those shape keys. The bones could be constrained as the drivers. Here's the link to the website and video guides you through how to use the add-on: https://www.blendernation.com/2015/05/18/addon-shape-driver-constraint/

Comment: Please avoid link only answers here. If the site goes down you answer becomes invalid and empty of content for future users. Please edit your question and provide a local explanation of how this could work.